# Operate on stretches of elements by shifting a window along a list of elements

Tags: python, string, list, sum

I am trying to operate on the sum of stretches of elements by moving by N along the list. For example, if I have `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']`, and I move by N=2, I would like to have `['A+B', 'B+C', 'C+D', 'D+E', 'E+F']`. Could you suggest a suitable way in Python?

Answer (score 3):

of course this can be implemented using just standard library tools, but you may want to have look at the nice [more-itertools package](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/)
there is [more_itertools.windowed](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#windowing)

```
import more_itertools

spam = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
for window in more_itertools.windowed(spam, 2):
    print(window) # do whatever you want with it
```

output:

```
('A', 'B')
('B', 'C')
('C', 'D')
('D', 'E')
('E', 'F')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension:

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

n = 2

result = [' + '.join(l[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(l)-(n-1))]
```

**Out:**

```
>>> result
['A + B', 'B + C', 'C + D', 'D + E', 'E + F']
```

Alternatively, if you actually want to sum the elements rather than creating a string, you could just use `sum()`.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

n = 2

result = [sum(l[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(l)-(n-1))]
```

**Out:**

```
>>> result
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```